# Custom response headers missing with AWS load balancer

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am trying to return a custom response header, X-Wrench-Status, from a private backend server on AWS (beanstalk) running Apache/Tomcat responding to a request from a web application. The request is proxied through an internet facing server running Apache. ProxyPass settings and CORS settings are all set up and running properly, have been for months.

The addition of the response header is new and I added

Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "X-Wrench-Status"

to my Apache configuration for this header. That works in my dev environment. But running in production behind AWS Elastic Load Balancers  the response header is not passed through. I have tried renaming the header and a few other things to see if some response header filter was just balking at my choice... no luck.

Is there some required configuration I am missing to get this to work?

Comment: Are you sure the header is really there?  Connect directly to the instance, to verify.

Comment: I am certain the header is there. I have connected directly to the instance to verify. This works as expected as configured until the load balancers are introduced.

Comment: Is this an ELB/1.0 "Classic Load Balancer" or ELB/2.0 "Application Load Balancer"...?

Comment: ELB/1.0 "Classic Load Balancer"